# Display text from jquery using json api response

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to display text from a api response which is in json format. i just need fresh loop though all "name" , " email" & number value. something like Name: John
Email : test@gmail.com
Number: 998755000

but using code bellow i am getting undefined error like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZjXp.png)

Json response from api-

```
[{"id":"1","name":"John","email":"test@gmail.com","numbers":"998755000"},{"id":"6","name":"Larry","email":"test@gmail.com","numbers":"5554888700"}]
```

Jquery code to display text-

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>The jQuery Example</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript"
         src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#driver").click(function(event){
               $.getJSON('api.php', function(jd) {
                  $('#stage').html('<p> Name: ' + jd.name + '</p>');
                  $('#stage').append('<p>Email : ' + jd.email+ '</p>');
                  $('#stage').append('<p> Number: ' + jd.number+ '</p>');
               });
            });

         });
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <p>Click on the button to load api.php file result:</p>
      <div id = "stage" style = "background-color:#cc0;">
         STAGE
      </div>
      <input type = "button" id = "driver" value = "Load Data" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The response from API is an array of objects. You have to iterate through that array

Comment: The use of html() as the first statement is going to wipe out all previous iterations of appended data...  This means only the last iteration of values will be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#driver").click(function(event){
    $.getJSON('api.php', function(data) {
      var newHTML = '';
      
      if (data && data.push) { //exists and it is an array
        newHTML = data.map(function(jd){
          return '<p> Name: '+ jd.name +'</p>'+
                 '<p>Email : '+ jd.email +'</p>'+
                 '<p> Number: '+ jd.numbers +'</p>';
        }).join('');
      }
      
      $('#stage').html(newHTML);
    });
  });
});
```

Using map we can loop over the results and generate the markup we want.  Doing so first allows us to perform a single html() on stage so only one page redraw happens, increasing performance over a redraw for every paragraph.

Comment: Should be jd.number**s**

Answer (score 2):

Since your requests returns a array of json objects. You need to iterate over the result with forEach.

```
     $("#driver").click(function(event){
           $.getJSON('api.php', function(data) {
              data.forEach(function(jd) {
                $('#stage').append('<p> Name: ' + jd.name + '</p>');
                $('#stage').append('<p>Email : ' + jd.email+ '</p>');
                $('#stage').append('<p> Number: ' + jd.number+ '</p>');
              });
           });
        });
```

Comment: yes it works but i am getting only first set of value. its not getting loop though all values yet. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

it's because the api returns an array.

```
$('#driver').click(function(event) {
  $.getJSON('api.php', function(jd) {

    console.log(jd); // add this and check your browser's console

    $('#stage').html('<p> Name: ' + jd.name + '</p>');
    $('#stage').append('<p>Email : ' + jd.email + '</p>');
    $('#stage').append('<p> Number: ' + jd.number + '</p>');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are receiving json array. You need to loop over the array, Here is a basic example.

```
jd.map(function(item, i){
 $('#stage').html('<p> Name: ' + item.name + '</p>');
                  $('#stage').append('<p>Email : ' + item.email+ '</p>');
                  $('#stage').append('<p> Number: ' + item.number+ '</p>');

});
```

Here is more detailed description of map function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control